# Firehose data transformation lambda - produce multiple records from single kinesis record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have created a Kinesis data stream and I'm feeding records into it that have format like this:

```py
{
    "ufo": 5,
    "unicorn": 7,
    "something else": 9,
}
```

I'm trying to write a transformation lambda that will transform above record and insert three records into Redshift. Redshift table schema is like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    timestamp DATETIME,
    name TEXT,
    count INT
) SORTKEY(timestamp);
```

So in essence - from single Kinesis record I need to produce three rows in Redshift.

[Documentation of transformation lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) does not explain if what I am trying to achieve is possible. I already tried to wrap all payload within array before encoding but this results in processing error on Redshift end. I also tried to return multiple records with the same record-id - this results in error too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across [this bit of documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html) which shows that multiple JSON objects can be stored within a single JSON file that is fed by COPY command. According documentation there can be more than one JSON object within the file and only white characters should be placed between JSON objects.

So I dropped objects like this:

```py
{"timestamp": "2020/07/17 00:00:00", "name": "ufo", "count": 5}
{"timestamp": "2020/07/17 00:00:00", "name": "unicorn", "count": 7}
{"timestamp": "2020/07/17 00:00:00", "name": "something else", "count": 9}
```

It's quite confusing to debug this since AWS is retrying failed records - I added new line between objects (which is what is being suggested within documentation) and at first I thought I'm getting errors but errors were for retried previous attempts.

Comment: did you find anything else? I need to save multiple records with different partition keys

Comment: Hi @MelihYıldız', I still use this approach which I outlined in the answer, though my cluster is the simplest one possible (I only have one node). Do you encounter errors when feeding Redshift with multiple JSONs per file?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm actually using kinesis DS to write to S3 and read it from there using Athena. I could not find a solution to this so I actually used a lambda "before" kinesis in my stack and used Direct PUT to put multiple records to the stream, instead of trying to do it in the transformer which is "after" the data is put.

Comment: @Greg0ry, do you need to specify a specific `delimiter` in the `COPY` options configuration?

Comment: @AndrewNguonly I can't see such option in documentation. [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html#copy-usage-json-options) specifies `auto`, `auto ignorecase`, or a `JSONPaths file`, but maybe I was not digging deep enough and there are options I don't know about. Delimiting with new line was my original solution which I stayed with and due to time pressure I stopped digging further..