# Kinesis Firehose - Split to multiple records while transforming a record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Is there an option to create multiple records from a single input record during transformation in Kinesis Firehose and store in parquet format in S3?

For example:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2_array": [
        {
            "subkey1": "1",
            "subkey2": "2"
        },
        {
            "subkey1": "3",
            "subkey2": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

should produce two records with for each key2_array elements. Example shown below:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2_split": 
        {
            "subkey1": "1",
            "subkey2": "2"
        }
}
```

I tried splitting the input record into multiple records with the same recordId of the input record, but transformation fails with the error

> Multiple records were returned with the same record Id. Ensure that the Lambda function returns a unique record Id for each record.

My understanding so far is that this option is not supported by Kinesis FireHose transformation pipeline. Is there a workaround or an alternative approach for this problem?

*Note - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935038/firehose-data-transformation-lambda-produce-multiple-records-from-single-kines) is a similar question but it deals with redshift.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, below are relevant pieces of how I do that for the similar use case of exploding nested lists of the incoming json objects:

```
def multiline_json_dumps(json_list):
    result = ""
    for json_object in json_list:
        result += json.dumps(json_object) + "\n"
    return result

[...]
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    records = event["records"]
    response_records = []
    for record in records:
        items = flatten_explode_json(record)  # this function returns a list of JSON objects
        response_records.append(
            {
                "recordId": record["recordId"],
                "result": "Ok",
                "data": base64.b64encode(multiline_json_dumps(items).encode("utf-8")),
            }
        )
    [...]
    return {"records": response_records}
```

Warning:
Lambda has a response size limit of 6Mb. Make sure your transformations do not blow up the response size above that limit. See this:
https://zaccharles.medium.com/deep-dive-lambdas-response-payload-size-limit-8aedba9530ed
It's baked into Firehose to rely on the response from lambda and there seems to be no way around this issue in Firehose itself.